# Angular2 component unable to receive a service in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service defined as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class SirService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log("The http is: " + http);
  }

  stuff() { return ["uno", "duo", "tress"]; }
}
```

Then, I'm setting the provider of my component to the service like this.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { SirService } from "../app.service";

@Component({
  selector: "demo",
  providers: [SirService],
  template: require("./demo.html"),
  styles: [require("./common.scss")]
})
export class Demo {
  // constructor() {
  constructor(private service: SirService) {
    console.log("Service: " + service);
  }
}
```

I'm uncertain how to access the `stuff()` call in the service, though. The above produces error telling me that Angular couldn't find anything meaningful to push into my constructor. When I use the parameterless constructor, I have no reference to the service. Kind of stuck there and there seems to be few examples showing how to do this for a component instead of a module... (I might be googling dumbly...)

The error message is humongous but this is the most relevant part (as far I can tell).

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for Http! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Comment: When you ask about an error, post the error. The complete and exact error.

Comment: @JBNizet I wasn't asking about the error as such, since the syntax is supposed to be correct as I compare to the resources but I do agree it might be of use. Please see the edit in 5 minutes. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @JBNizet Posted. It's full content is too huge to show but the edit shows the interesting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

```
No provider for Http
```

That means that the problem is not with your service. the problem is that your service needs to use the Http service, and this service doesn't exist.

You need to import the HttpModule, which provides this service:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [BrowserModule, ..., HttpModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

More explanations in [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#http-providers)

Comment: Aha! So there's no way to compartmentalize the service class and the component to be the only ones aware of the `HttpModule`? I do have to put it in the imports section of the decorator of my module? I mean, after all, I did import it into the service imports (line 2).

Comment: Yes. Your service, since it's completely stateless, could also be provided by the root module: there's no real point creating a new instance for each instance of your component. You could make a submodule for this component and this service, but I don't really see the point. You'll use Http everywhere anyway.

Comment: Interesting point. I get that. I tried to laborate with different approaches to see what's working, what doesn't and - most importantly - why is does or doesn't.